# How to fix an overheating Arduino nano?

Tags: arduino, overheat

I have an Arduino Nano and when I power it either via USB or VIN it heats up very quickly. Before it started to overheat I heard a spark but didn't see which pin sparked and I think that's the problem. During the spark I had a L293N motor drivers one IN pin was connected to the board. I tried uploading the blink sketch and disconnecting everything but still having the same problem. I can't see any visual issues on the board. How may I fix it?

Comment: Does *blinky* run properly?

Comment: Yes, everything runs normally but it just overheats.

Comment: At 15-20 currency units, a repair could cost more than replacement, especially if you don't already have SMD placement/cooking tools.  Even if parts cost didn't go over, time cost would very quickly.  Have you checked input voltage and current when it's overheating?

Answer (score 1):

If no loads are active and power recycled for unlatch-up effects, fails to resume normal power dissipation, then it’s SNAFU’d by overvoltage.

Comment: Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @EnesDoğan Your best bet would be to trash this nano and get a new one. These are pretty cheap

Comment: I told you how to recycle power , how to prevent these “cat a strophic” failures  needs more data to analyze